# Bootstrap 4.2 and my layout and rows are not horizontally centered

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I want to create a simple layout in Bootstrap 4.2 where I have a logo, banner, breadcrumb, menu, content and a footer - nothing fancy in this and it should be pretty standard. It should of course also be responsive for tablets and phones but I will tackle this when I understand the grid system. I have read the [grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/) and the [display properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/display/) and tried now for a couple of days to understand this but sadly I did not get it right so I would appreciate some hints what I am doing wrong.

I have this current code:

```
<!-- Top container -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Sticky top for Logo + Banner + Breadcrumb -->
    <div class="row sticky-top">

        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <!-- Row 1, Logo + Banner -->

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="row col-lg-2 bg-primary">
            Logo
        </div>

        <!-- Banner -->
        <div class="row col-lg-8 bg-warning">
            Banner
        </div>

        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <!-- Row 2, Breadcrumb -->

        <!-- Breadcrumb -->
        <div class="row col-lg-10 bg-secondary">
            Breadcrumb
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Sticky top for Logo + Banner + Breadcrumb -->

    <!-- ----------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- Row 3, Menu + Content -->

    <!-- Menu + Content -->
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Menu -->
        <div class="col-lg-2 bg-success">
            Menu
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="col-lg-8 bg-info">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Menu + Content -->

    <!-- ----------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- Row 4, Footer -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="col-lg-10 bg-danger">
        Footer
    </div>

    <!-- ----------------------------------------------------------- -->

</div> <!-- Top container -->
```

The above layout looks like this in the **Large** viewport:

[image: My layout]

This looks very weird and I do not understand this at all so I have these couple of questions:

- Why are the 4 rows not horizontally aligned to each other?
- How can I get the entire page to be horizontally aligned to the center?

  - I am only using 10 columns of the 12 in the Bootstrap grid system as I do not want to use the entire page in the **Large** viewport (`col-lg-2` for menu and `col-lg-8` for content)

I have a JSFiddle for it - please view it in a maximized window: http://jsfiddle.net/0tw2dk3o/

---

**SOLUTION** as proposed by @joykal-infotech is this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1n95jLz2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should like this: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smho3ebL/)

You have missed `row` and `column` classes ordering and formatting.

Comment: This does not fix the footer nor is the entire page not horizontal center aligned?

Comment: Please Check now.

Comment: That seems to fix the footer but the page is still not horizontal centered? There is more white space to the right than to the left.

Comment: You have added `offset-lg-1` to each of the first columns but do you care to elaborate? I do see it fixes the problem but is this really the correct Bootstrap way of solving this?

Comment: Yes, this is a correct way to practice, as Bootstrap provides you with these options, i assume that you have read this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ which also provides you a option of adding class 'justify-content-center' with class 'row'. Hope more you can learn through this link. If then too arises a problem feel free to post.

Comment: Hope this helps and you accept and upvote the answer. Thanks !!